# Ensemble learning with different data sets

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, ensemble-learning

Consider model A, a deployed model that produces a probabilty of if an event occur or not for a population.

This I want to improve by building another model, model B, on top of model A. Model B should return adjusted probabilities for the same event.

The data for model B is monthly. For model A it’s annual. The features are not the same.

Questions:

- Can I use the returned probabilties from model A to enable model B to be derived on model A?
- Could the probabilties from model A be used in a stacking design with model B?
- How could/should this problem be approach?

Comment: This depends on the model type as well, but sounded like additive modelling.

Comment: Model A is logistic regression, model B could be any model that works.

Comment: @patagonicus additive modelling, you mean GAM?

Comment: @patagonicus additive modelling, you mean GAM?